# How many process can run on one thread in CPU?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

How many process can run on one thread in CPU at the moment? For example, if I have CPU with 4 threads. I need to know how does it work

Answer (score 0):

As many as it needs to but not at the same time.
The computer will most likely make use of the other threads as well.